# rep:50125:rwbuilder.conf:java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: oracle11g, runtime-error, oraclereports

When i run oracle reports 11g in my windows 7 it gives me this error
`rep:50125:rwbuilder.conf:java.lang.NullPointerException`

My run shortcut path is

`G:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\bin\rwbuilder.exe`

Comment: I had the similar problem half year ago, but I just inserted  *\*\Middleware\asinst_1\config\reports\bin\reports.bat before *\*\Middleware\as_1\bin\rwbuilder.exe.

Comment: yes you are right but is it oracle bug !?

Comment: No,in Oracle 11g Forms and Reports comunicate throug Oracle Instance, so Oracle Reports uses Oracle Instance configuration. You can read more in: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_run008.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it in my case go to oracle directory and search for rwbuilder.bat it will show three results , one is in the path i.e in my case
`D:\Oracle\Middleware\asinst_1\config\reports\bin\rwbuilder.bat` try to run and it will work

This solution is for the most but not the only and may not solve your problem

Comment: In 12c:

   C:\Dev12c\mw\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\reports\bin\rwbuilder.bat

Comment: @AbdelmonemMahmoudAmer your solucion for 12c was correct

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd go to oracle path

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\asinst_1\bin>
```

Then write your command

```
opmnctl createcomponent -adminUsername weblogic -adminHost SERVERNAME -adminPort 7001 -oracleInstance c:\oracle\middleware\asinst_1 -instanceName asinst_1 -componentName MYREPSERVERNAME -componentType ReportsServerComponent

opmnctl startproc ias-component=MYREPSERVERNAME
```

Comment: this code suppose to fix or do what !? more explanation -- is it from your experience or link reference